# jqPlot multiple series labels with multiple yaxis

Tags: jqplot, series, yaxis

I have some multiple series for jqPlot with labels correctly stored in:

```
data.labels=[[label:'A'],[label:'B'],[label:'C']]....
```

which I can successfully use by:

```
series: data.labels,
highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 6,
            tooltipContentEditor: customTooltip,
            formatString: '#serieLabel#<br/>%s - %s',
            bringSeriesToFront: true,
        },
```

Also I have series on different yaxis which I defined by:

```
series:[
        { yaxis: "yaxis" },
        { yaxis: "y2axis" },
        { yaxis: "y3axis" },
        { yaxis: "y4axis" },                
        { yaxis: "y5axis" },
        { yaxis: "y6axis" },
        { yaxis: "y7axis" },
        { yaxis: "y8axis" },
        { yaxis: "y9axis" }
],
```

Еach series option work OK, but the problem is I need both together. I don't know how to specify both of them to make working both my series names when highlight and multiple yaxis ?

My second question - Is there a way to prevent yaxis duplications, because I have three series showing voltages (12.0 - 220.0V) and two series with ampere (0.05 - 1.0A) ?

Comment: Anyone with solution?

Answer (score 0):

And this is my solution:

```
        seriesDefaults: { 
            series: data.labels,
        },
        series: [
            { yaxis: "yaxis", label: data.labels[0] },
            { yaxis: "y2axis", label: data.labels[1] },
            { yaxis: "y3axis", label: data.labels[2] },
            { yaxis: "y4axis", label: data.labels[3] },
            { yaxis: "y5axis", label: data.labels[4] },
            { yaxis: "y6axis", label: data.labels[5] },
            { yaxis: "y7axis", label: data.labels[6] },
            { yaxis: "y8axis", label: data.labels[7] },
            { yaxis: "y9axis", label: data.labels[8] }
        ],
```